# how to invalidate session in spring mvc for implementing logout

Tags: java, spring, session, model-view-controller, annotations

I have set the session attributes using

```
@SessionAttribute annotation.
@RequestMapping(value = "/login_action")
public ModelAndView login_action(@RequestParam("email") String email,@RequestParam("password") String password){
                Query q=session.createSQLQuery("SELECT User_ID,User_First_Name,User_Last_Name,Email,User_Type,Program,Level,Gender FROM Users  WHERE Email=:email AND Password=:password");
q.setParameter("email",email);
q.setParameter("password",password);
Object u = (Object) q.uniqueResult();
model=new ModelAndView("profile");
model.addObject("user",u);
return model;
}
```

Now i need to invalidate this session while logging out.
I tried like

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout")
    public ModelAndView logout(HttpSession sess){
        sess.invalidate();
        model.addObject("view","home");
        return model;
    }
```

can i have some answers with some examples.

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the result of your logout code?

Comment: it is not working,the session variable "user" is still stored

Answer (score 1):

From the [javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html)

> NOTE: Session attributes as indicated using this annotation correspond
>   to a specific handler's model attributes, getting transparently stored
>   in a conversational session. Those attributes will be removed once the
>   handler indicates completion of its conversational session. Therefore,
>   use this facility for such conversational attributes which are
>   supposed to be stored in the session temporarily during the course of
>   a specific handler's conversation.
>
> For permanent session attributes, e.g. a user authentication object,
>   use the traditional session.setAttribute method instead.
>   Alternatively, consider using the attribute management capabilities of
>   the generic WebRequest interface.

When using SessionAttributes typically you use SessionStatus `setComplete`

I think you might be better off using spring security with an authentication provider and something like UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. Your user/principal would be accessible via SecurityContextHolder and included in the HttpSession. When using spring security you then could use/configure a LogoutConfigurer to invalidate the session and clears the SecurityContextHolder context and sets the authentication to null.

Side note: I hope this isn't for anything other than a demo/poc as it appears that you are storing passwords as plain text